# Performing Division using Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Is there anyway of performing division (say a div b) using binary search tree.

Comment: whats the context? what have you tried?

Comment: Binary Search tree can be created before performing division. So I tried creating binary search tree with value 0....a and tree is balance

Comment: What data does your tree represent? It sounds like you're misremembering that binary trees can be used [to represent mathematical expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree).

Comment: Tree contains integer value. We can construct our own tree base on the input from the user.

Comment: Any binary integer can be considered as a path in a binary tree that contains all integers (0 for left branch, 1 for right branch), so every calculation can be thought of as searching the tree for a leaf with given properties. Is this what you mean?